# Spring data R2DBC, saveAll() in one sql query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

In ReactiveCrudRepository we have saveAll methods

```
<S extends T> reactor.core.publisher.Flux<S> saveAll(org.reactivestreams.Publisher<S> entityStream)
<S extends T> reactor.core.publisher.Flux<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities)
```

When we save collection with N elements, N queries are made not one. For example if we save collection with 2 elements, we get 2 queries like :

```
INSERT INTO test(id, value) VALUES (111, "value1");
INSERT INTO test(id, value) VALUES (222, "value2");
```

Is there a way to make this in one SQL query?

```
INSERT INTO test(id, value) VALUES  (111, "value1"), (222, "value2");
```

It may be needed to map to Mono, but this is ok for me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think this is not currently supported.
Looking in the spring-data-relational library, the Insert statement accept a list of values, but each value corresponding to one column, no way to add different rows.

If you look deeper in this library, the [InsertBuilder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/main/spring-data-relational/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/relational/core/sql/InsertBuilder.java) interface declares methods like this one:

```java
         /**
         * Add one or more {@link Expression values} to the {@code VALUES} list. Calling this method multiple times will add
         * a {@link Expression values} multiple times.
         *
         * @param values the values.
         * @return {@code this} builder.
         * @see Column
         */
        @Override
        InsertValuesWithBuild values(Expression... values);
```

And the implementation store those values into a list of expressions (class [DefaultInsertBuilder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/main/spring-data-relational/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/relational/core/sql/DefaultInsertBuilder.java)):

```java
/**
 * Default {@link InsertBuilder} implementation.
 *
 * @author Mark Paluch
 * @since 1.1
 */
class DefaultInsertBuilder
        implements InsertBuilder, InsertBuilder.InsertIntoColumnsAndValuesWithBuild, InsertBuilder.InsertValuesWithBuild {

    private @Nullable Table into;
    private List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Expression> values = new ArrayList<>();

[...]
```

Then, the renderer class (converting the statement into an SQL string) is adding those values into VALUES(...) each value separated by a comma (class [InsertStatementVisitor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/main/spring-data-relational/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/relational/core/sql/render/InsertStatementVisitor.java)):

```java
        if (segment instanceof Insert) {

            builder.append("INSERT");

            builder.append(" INTO ").append(into);

            if (columns.length() != 0) {
                builder.append(" (").append(columns).append(")");
            }

            builder.append(" VALUES (").append(values).append(")");

            return Delegation.leave();
        }
```

with the values filled here in the [ValuesVisitor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/main/spring-data-relational/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/relational/core/sql/render/ValuesVisitor.java) class:

```java
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                builder.append(", ");
            }

            builder.append(this.current.getRenderedPart());
```

So the code of spring-data-relational shows that having a SQL like `VALUES(...),(...)` is not possible for now.